# Call GoogleApiClient SignOut from another Activity in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, google-play-services, google-api-client

I want to have a sign out button in a Fragment I called "Profile". This fragment is in my MainActivity. But I can't get the right GoogleApiClient object to disconnect user.

My Sign In button is in another Activity, called AuthenticationActivity, and I can't see how I can send the object to my current MainActivity.

I tried to create another GoogleApiClient object in my fragment, but it returns me that I'm not connected. Is it possible or am I doing wrong ?

A little bit of my code :

ProfileFragment.java

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(rootView.getContext().getApplicationContext())
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
...


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            signOutFromGplus();
            break;
    }
}

...
    private void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        sessionManager.destroySession();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing "getActivity()" as context in new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity());

Comment: Nothing change, my test `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected` return false

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html these connections should be made in Activity rather than fragments.. You can try that and check for connections in fragment by isConnected().

Comment: You mean that I must export this code on my MainActivity, and call isConnected through my Fragment ?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I tried to put all my code in my MainActivity, and call isConnected() from my fragment, but it returns me false too...

Comment: It would be better separating the LoginActivity concerns from the authentication, turning the authenticator an observable state machine. See http://goo.gl/YZ0dnY. This way you can access it from others activities (or fragments).